# Is Rubezov still alive?

Tags: history, famous-players

Anatoly Rubezov vs Georgy Borisenko (1960) was a famous correspondence game.

```
[Event "USSR Correspondence Championship"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "1960.??.??"]
[EventDate "?"]
[Round "?"]
[Result "0-1"]
[White "Anatoly Rubezov"]
[Black "Georgy Konstantinovich Borisenko"]
[ECO "B89"]
[WhiteElo "?"]
[BlackElo "?"]
[PlyCount "74"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 d6 6. Bc4 e6
7. O-O Be7 8. Be3 O-O 9. Bb3 Na5 10. f4 b6 11. g4 Bb7 12. Qf3
Rc8 13. g5 Rxc3 14. gxf6 Rxe3 15. Qxe3 Bxf6 16. Rad1 Nxb3
17. axb3 a6 18. e5 dxe5 19. Nxe6 Qc8 20. Nxf8 Qc6 21. Kf2 Qg2+
22. Ke1 Bh4+ 23. Rf2 Bf3 24. Rd8 Qg1+ 25. Kd2 Qd1+ 26. Kc3
Qxd8 27. Rxf3 e4 28. Rh3 Bf6+ 29. Kc4 Qc7+ 30. Kd5 Qb7+
31. Kd6 Kxf8 32. Rxh7 Be7+ 33. Ke5 f6+ 34. Ke6 Qc6+ 35. Kf5
Qc8+ 36. Kxe4 Qxc2+ 37. Kd5 Qxh7 0-1
```

I found nothing about Anatoly Rubezov in the internet. Does anyone know when he was born , whether he is still alive and if not , when he died ?

Answer (score 6):

There is certainly not a lot of information about Anatoly Rubezov (Анатолий Рубезов).

From the book [Гродзенский С.Я., "Шахматная почта России: турниры, партии, личности, 2015" (Grodzenskiy S. Ya., "Correspondence Chess Russia: Tournaments, Games, Personalities")](https://litgid.com/read/shakhmatnaya_pochta_rossii_turniry_partii_lichnosti/page-6.php):

[image]

It is clear, that Anatoly Rubezov is from [**Sverdlovsk Oblast**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sverdlovsk_Oblast). That is probably the only certain information about them that you don't have in your question.

---

<sup>There are some unrelated-to-chess records in Russian about some Anatoly [Igorevich] Rubezov from Sverdlovsk Region in the Russian court system from 2021, but I am extremely certain **they are a different person** (simply judging by age).</sup>